# how do I undo a checkout in subversion 1.7?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

In our workflow, we have a script that checks out externals to an ext/ directory. Prior to 1.7 I could delete that folder, do an update, and I would have a directory containing lots of other (empty) directories. Run the script again and I have my external sources back where they were.

I realize that there is a svn:externals property that I can set on ext/ to do this automatically and in fact that is where my problem lies. Someone has already changed one of the folders to an svn:external. When I do an update, it gives me this fine error message:

Fetching external item into 'folder':
svn: warning: W155004: '

At revision 78884.
svn: E205011: Failure occurred processing one or more externals definitions

Short of deleting my entire project/ folder, is there any way to tell svn 1.7 to stop populating my ext/folder/ from the local copy?

Comment: Does this prevent you from committing ? If not, then just remove the property and commit it again.

Comment: not committing, just updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to resolve my issue of switched directory / externals clashing by:

```
svn up -r <previous revision>
svn up folder  // this command picked up the deletion of the folder out of my ext
rm -rf folder
```

At this point, both commands `svn ls` and `ls -al` show that folder does not exist.

`svn up` then proceeded to do the right thing